# Помогите новичку разработать простенькую игру!

Tags: python, python-3.x

Играют два игрока.  Есть **10** палочек. Игроки по очереди берут от **одной** до **трёх** палочек. Играют до тех пор пока не закончатся палочки. Тот кто взял последним - тот проиграл.

Реализуйте игру таким образом, чтобы могли играть **два** человека. Изначально есть **10** палочек. На каждом ходу выводите на консоль текущее количество оставшихся палочек и просите ввести количество палочек, которое хочет взять игрок (который делает ход). Не забывайте менять очерёдность игроков и сокращать кол-во палочек. В конце надо вывести кто победил - **первый** или **второй** игрок.

**P.S.** Прошу, напишите к каждому шагу объяснение, иначе мне не понять, спасибо!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как то так

```py
count_of_sticks = int(input('введите количество палочек для игры: '))
gamer_1, gamer_2 = input('введите имя 1 игрока: '), input('введите имя 2 игрока: ')
current_gamer = gamer_1
while count_of_sticks > 0:
    print('количество оставшихся палочек: {}'.format(count_of_sticks))
    while True:
        number_to_delete = int(input('ход игрока {} (1 - 3): '.format(current_gamer)))
        if number_to_delete >= 1 and number_to_delete <= 3:
            break
    count_of_sticks -= number_to_delete
    current_gamer = gamer_2 if current_gamer == gamer_1 else gamer_1

print('Победил {}'.format(current_gamer))
```

Comment: gamer = (gamer % 2) + 1 #смена игрока
Объясни пожалуйста, как так происходит, что игроки меняются, а то я не догоняю

Comment: И не мог бы ты ещё показать, как сделать проверку: если игрок взял меньше 1 или больше 3 палочек, то нужно заново ввести кол-во удаляемых палочек.

Comment: объяснить что тут происходит?
это функция остатка от деления или же mod, в python она реализована как %, то есть я беру остаток от деления на 2, для 1 это 2, для 2 это 0, то есть если я получаю 1 и плюсую 1, 1 меняется на 2, а если было 2, я получу 0 и прибавлю 1

Comment: Всё, понял, спасибо огромное, очень помог!)

Comment: я добавлю проверку в код, смотри

Comment: Осталось понять, как работает проверка

Comment: Секунду........

Comment: проверка простая, число должно быть в диапазоне от 1 до 3 включительно

Comment: если помог клацни галочку, спасибо)

Comment: Блин, дружище, реально всё классно объяснил, спасибо ещё раз)

Comment: да не за что, почитай книжку Марка Лутца, там все круто и подробно, удачи)

Comment: player_turn = 1 if player_turn == 2 else 2     Я видел вот такое решение смены игроков, но его тяжелее твоего понять

Comment: А какое издание? Или сразу все?

Comment: 5 самое новое, хотя там есть фрагменты python 2.7.6, но все же.

а в этом способе используется тернарный оператор, если грубо переменная будет 1 если она равна двум, иначе, если она не равна двум, она ей станет

Comment: Извини, если замучил тебя, но я тут добавил input'ы 2-ух игроков, но теперь не понимаю как вообще с ними производить смену? Поможешь?

Comment: ты про имена, или что?

Comment: Именно!.............

Comment: если есть дискорд, то вот ссылка - https://discord.gg/EB63XBa, я подробно расскажу, если нет, то пропишу, изменил код

Comment: Захожу.........